# how do I make a new filesystem image?

Tags: command-line, disk-image, mkfs

I know I used to be able to do it, and its frustrating I cant recall.
I want to write an ext4 filesystem to a disk image in a folder. I don't want to re-partition my drive, I just need the filesystem to build an OS in.
I tried `$mkdir foo` then `sudo mkfs.ext4 foo 70000`
`mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020) warning: Unable to get device geometry for foo foo: Is a directory while setting up superblock`

so i think Im missing arguments. I tried reading the man page, and the ol google, but I did not see and example of using mkfs.ext4 to create a new disk image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a disk image, you need to operate on a *file*, not on a *directory*:

```
# Create a file of some specific size for the new image
truncate -s 10g disk.img

# Format the image with a new filesystem
mkfs -t ext4 disk.img
```

You can mount the image using the `loop` mount option:

```
mount -o loop disk.img /mnt
```

---

Note that the above instructions are for creating a *filesystem image*. If you want to create a *bootable* image, you will probably want to partition the file, install a bootloader, etc, which is a slightly more involved process.